# blueimp image gallary in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blueimp

I am using blueimp image gallary. I need to change modal width depending on content so I am using onopen event of blueimp but it is not working. I have read the documentation but it did not help me. https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#video-factory-options. Am I missing something

```
$('.abc').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        blueimp.Gallery($('.abctag a'),$('#blueimp-gallery').data(),{
onopen:function(){
//do something
}
})
})

<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog videoGallary">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">                        
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next                        
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, did you solve it? Same thing here.

Comment: $('.new-campaigns').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  blueimp.Gallery($('.outdoorTag a:lt(34)'),{container:'#blueimp-gallery',continuous:false,onopen:function(a,b){
    if(screen.width<992){
      $(this.container).find('.modal-dialog').addClass('displayImgMobile')
    }
  }})
})

Comment: Its works fine for me